# array assignment with weird result

Tags: c, for-loop, variable-assignment

the problem is aasigning a 2-D array to a 1-D array

```
uint8_t Schedules[24][8]={
 {0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0},
 {0,2,2,2,2,2,2,0},
 {0,3,3,3,3,3,3,0},
 ...
 {0,24,24,24,24,24,24,0}
}


for (this_hour=0;this_hour<24;this_hour++){
        for(this_section=1;this_section<7;this_section++)
        {
            buff[this_hour*9+this_section+2]=Schedules[this_hour][this_section];
        }
    }
```

the result must be

```
buff[3..8]=1; /* Pseudocode; means buff[3]=1, buff[4]=1, ..., buff[8]=1 */
buff[9..11]=0;
buff[12..17]=2;
buff[18..20]=0,
...
```

however, this is the result

[image: debugger result Image]

I don't know where I am wrong. I ten times checked for loop and did not find any thing wrong. I am writing in freertos in keil 5 for stm32 ARM. I make sure that buff is accessed just in for loop and no other place in code. it is not stack overflow because I give stack a big number

Comment: Why multiply by 9?

Comment: `this_section` should be initialized to 0, not 1. and the index of `buff` should be `this_hour*8+this_section`. The 8 is because there are 8 elements in each of the 2nd dimension arrays. There is no need to add an offset of 2.

Comment: 9 is part of my program , I have 9 section and 6 of them filled with schedules 3 others are going to be  filled later. I have 3 header byte in the beginning of buff. they are not important , why buff is filled incorrectly?

Comment: @kevinmont ,I did all of that deliberately, this numbers multiply by 9 and 2 as offset is part of my program

Comment: I see. What are you expecting as an output? The notation you put says that buff[8] should be 1 and 0. So you have 3 0s of padding, 6 1s, another 3 0s of padding (?) etc.?

Comment: @kevinmont ou are right about issues ,I edited my question and correct it and  yes again you are right,I have 3 "0"s of header bytes then 6 "1"s, another  3 "0"s then 6 "2"s,then 3 "0" and so  on.

Comment: `for (this_section = 0; .. ` and just `buff[this_hour  * 8  + this_section]=Schedules[this_hour][this_section];`

Comment: @KamilCuk ,no It is not working

Comment: The pattern of your output says you have heap corruption somewhere else.

Comment: @Joshua, Any suggestion to make sure if it is by heap or not

Comment: @david: I am absolutely certain it's not in the code you posted.

Comment: This [does not reproduce](https://ideone.com/YFQW8K). Please post a [mcve], and no pictures of numbers.

Comment: @Joshua, I created a task variable instead of globally variable for "Schedules" and it is now working , you are right about memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Joshua said in comments there is a problem in memory and code is correct. I created a local variable and It is working.

the cuprit was a wrong declaraion

```
extern uint8_t Schedules[24][11];
```

the definition of this array is

```
extern uint8_t Schedules[24][8];
```

second parameter of array in extern declaration was wrong.so code write in memory that can not be seen in debug

Answer (score 1):

Like this,array is from 0,mean

Schedules[x][y] x,y is position will appear below

x*8+y

0......7    mapped from 0,0~0,7

8......15    mapped from 1,0~1,7

16......23    mapped from 2,0~2,7

........

@kevinmont ou are right about issues ,I edited my question and correct it and yes again you are right,I have 3 "0"s of header bytes then 6 "1"s, another 3 "0"s then 6 "2"s,then 3 "0" and so on. – david 6 hours ago

need array size is 24*9+1+2

x*9+y+2

2......9    mapped from 0,0~0,7

11......18    mapped from 1,0~1,7

20......27    mapped from 2,0~2,7

........

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef unsigned char uint8_t;
uint8_t Schedules[24][8]={
{0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0},
{0,2,2,2,2,2,2,0},
{0,3,3,3,3,3,3,0},
{0,4,4,4,4,4,4,0},
{0,5,5,5,5,5,5,0},
{0,6,6,6,6,6,6,0},
{0,7,7,7,7,7,7,0},
{0,8,8,8,8,8,8,0},
{0,9,9,9,9,9,9,0},
{0,10,10,10,10,10,10,0},
{0,11,11,11,11,11,11,0},
{0,12,12,12,12,12,12,0},
{0,13,13,13,13,13,13,0},
{0,14,14,14,14,14,14,0},
{0,15,15,15,15,15,15,0},
{0,16,16,16,16,16,16,0},
{0,17,17,17,17,17,17,0},
{0,18,18,18,18,18,18,0},
{0,19,19,19,19,19,19,0},
{0,20,20,20,20,20,20,0},
{0,21,21,21,21,21,21,0},
{0,22,22,22,22,22,22,0},
{0,23,23,23,23,23,23,0},
{0,24,24,24,24,24,24,0}
};

int main(){
    int this_hour,this_section,i;
    uint8_t buff[192]={0};//24*8
    for (this_hour=0;this_hour<24;this_hour++){
        for(this_section=0;this_section<8;this_section++)
        {
            buff[this_hour*8+this_section]=Schedules[this_hour][this_section];
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<192;i++){

        if(i!=0 && i%8==0){
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("%d",buff[i]);
    }

    printf("\n------------------------------------\n");


    uint8_t buff2[219]={0};//24*9+1+2
    for (this_hour=0;this_hour<24;this_hour++){
        for(this_section=0;this_section<8;this_section++)
        {
            buff2[this_hour*9+this_section+2]=Schedules[this_hour][this_section];
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<219;i++){

        if(i!=0 && i%9==0){
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("%d",buff2[i]);
    }





    return 0;
}
```

Comment: my problem is not how to write the code ,but why my code not worked? your code does not work for me again .

Comment: Compiler gcc or armcc ?  and your Optimize

Comment: ARM C/C++ Compilers and I checked no optimize and optimized both no difference ,as I wrote in answer it is a memory issue

Comment: Ok i understand you split main file and Schedules in different file....